# How to Convert Cordova Image Picker Results to Base64 format?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Hi I want to know how to Convert the Image Picker Results to Base64 , While Getting the image through **Cordova Camera** I can get base64 format data but in **cordova image picker** it does not working

I have Seen the below link and applied its Working for Cordova Camera Image Capture but not working for cordova image picker

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456897/cordova-image-picker-convert-to-base64
```

**Not Working for cordova image Picker**

```
 $scope.Pick=function(){
  var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation:true
    };

  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function (results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
      }
      $scope.results=results;
    }, function(error) {
    });

};
```

**Working For Cordova Image Capture**

```
$scope.captureimage=function()
{
 var options = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation:true
    };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

      $scope.cimage=imageData;
      alert($scope.cimage);
    }, function(err) {
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pickimage returns an URI not the image data. Here's the code that should do what you want:

```
 $scope.Pick=function(){
  var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation:true
    };

  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function (results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(results[i],
            function (fileEntry) {
                // convert to Base64 string


                fileEntry.file(
                    function(file) {
                        //got file
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                            var imgData = evt.target.result; // this is your Base64 string
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }, 
                function (evt) { 
                    //failed to get file
                });
            },
            // error callback
            function () { }
        );
      }


      $scope.results=results;
    }, function(error) {
    });

};
```

Comment: @coding-dude.com when I run it with `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova run browser` it return base64 directly, and when I run it on android `ionic cordova run android` it return the img URI, how to solve that?